# Pie charts changing colors

Tags: reporting, dashboard

What are the steps to be followed to change the default pie chart colors of dashboards in salesforce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now it doesn't look like possible. You can vote this idea.

[More Report and Dashboard Chart Color Customization](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000KLLvAAO)

If you are using picklist field then you can assign them color

- Click Edit next to a value to change the name, make it the default picklist value, assign a color to use on charts, or change additional information.
- Click Del next to a value to remove it from the picklist.

Special picklists—such as opportunity Stage, Task Priority, Task Status, Lead Status, and Case Status—may prompt you to map the deleted value to another existing value in all of your organization’s records. You can map the values or leave your existing data unchanged.

- Click New to add values to the picklist. If you use record types, select any record types that you want to include the new values.
- Click Reorder to change the sequence of picklist values.
- Click Replace to change the values of picklist fields in existing records.
- Click Printable View to open an easy-to-print list of your picklist values.
- Click Chart Colors and select an option to assign colors to picklist values for use in charts:

Assign fixed colors to all values assigns a fixed color to each value from the standard set of chart colors. The Chart Colors column shows the assigned colors. Manually change assigned colors by editing picklist values. For example, if you want Closed Lost values to always show up as red in charts grouped by Opportunity Stage, assign red to that picklist value.

Assign colors to values dynamically assigns colors when a chart is generated. The Chart Colors column shows “Assigned dynamically” for all colors. Assign fixed colors by editing picklist values. For example, if you only need certain picklist values to show up as fixed colors in charts, manually assign colors to those values and leave the rest as “Assigned dynamically.”

[Set Colors for Picklist Values in Charts](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/162/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_winter10_release_notes.pdf#rn_162_analytics__rn_picklist_colors)

Comment: Hi Tushar Sharma,Nice explanation & Thanks for the info.